# While loop in JS to get folder path

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make work a while loop in JS but I do not know much about js syntax.
Each time I test the following code I get an error 'out of memory", so I think I need to fix the code but cant' find what is not working

```js
const template = [
    {title: 'template 1', parentFolder:'', uniqueid: '1'},
    {title: 'template 2-2', parentFolder:'', uniqueid: '22'},
    {title: 'template 2-2', parentFolder:'', uniqueid: '222'},
    {title: 'template 2-2-1', parentFolder:'', uniqueid: '333'},
];

template[0].parentFolder = template[0];
template[1].parentFolder = template[0];
template[2].parentFolder = template[0];
template[3].parentFolder = template[1];

// Function and get the folder to start from
function getFoldersPath(currentFolder) {

  // Create an empty list to hold the full path
  const previousParents = [];

  // Add each parentFolder to the list until reaching the root parent

  while (currentFolder.uniqueid !== template[0].uniqueid) {
    previousParents.push(currentFolder.uniqueid);
    currentFolder = currentFolder.parentFolder.uniqueid;
  }
  return previousParents;
}

var result = getFoldersPath(template[3])
console.log(result)
```

If someone could help me fix the code

Comment: Don't put quotes around `currentFolder.uniqueid`. That makes it a string literal, not a variable.

Comment: In case this isn’t self-evident: you’re pushing a literal string into an array repeatedly until you run out of memory because your while condition is never true.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I removed the quotes from all variables. So i do not have the error anymore. But my result is empty